# Show a button when scrolls the map using Google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using a Google Maps v2 to show the locations plotted on it. I unhide a refresh button when scrolls on the map. I just used `CameraChange` method to get the callback, but it is getting called when I search for a location using the Edit text or fetch current location. How to limit this to get callback when I manually scroll on the Map.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simple `OnTouchListener` will work just fine.

You will write your custom class which extends the `OnTouchListener`. This class will track the map's position when `ACTION_DOWN` occurs (user touches the map), compare it with the map's position when `ACTION_UP` occurs (user lifts the finger off the map), and, if there's change, you can hide/show your refresh button.

Once you write it, add it to the map via `MapView#setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener listener)` method.